# How do I plot a variogram?

Tags: variogram

I have a variogram exported from Supervisor which contains (in this case) the Nugget, Sill and Range for two Structures in four directions.

How can I use this as inputs into a plot?

Is there some way to calculate a "fake" covariance for certain distances so I can draw a line between XY points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to draw either Spherical or Gaussian variogram model as you have Nugget, Sill and Range.

If you have Microsoft Excel, the setting would be like below image:

[image]

Formula for the **Spherical model** (Cell [B7]) is

```
=$B$2+($B$3-$B$2)*IF(A7>$B$4, 1, 1.5*A7/$B$4-0.5*A7^3/$B$4^3)
```

and please copy the cell down.

The **Gaussian model** (Cell C7) is:

```
=$B$2+($B$3-$B$2)*(1-EXP(-(A7/$B$4)^2))
```

The above image shows `blue line`= *Spherical model* while `orange line` = *Gaussian model*.

Not sure if you have expected an Excel spreadsheet, but hope this provides you with a starter.